# Turning on auto-fill mode as a minor mode when I run emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have the following code to have auto-fill mode as minor mode when I run emacs/org-mode.

```
(defun my-org-mode-hook()
  (progn
    (turn-on-flyspell)
    (auto-fill-mode)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
```

But, when I open the org file, I see only (Org Fly Spc): flyspell mode is on, but not the auto-fill mode is not on.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Does anyone know why (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
or even
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill) does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

auto-fill-mode without an argument toggles the mode. Try using

```
(auto-fill-mode 1)
```

in your hook instead?